# What does upcasting and downcasting look at? (Object type or Reference type)

Tags: java, casting, reference, downcast, upcasting

I am a beginner and I am confused between these two examples. So sorry if I ask something that has already be answered. I don't know how to search for this issue.

Let's say I have class Person and class Student. Student extends Person.
So when I do:

```
 Student student = (Student)new Person();
```

I get ClassCastException. Which makes sense (Person is not instance of Student).

But when I do this:

```
Person p = new Student();
        Student s = (Student)p;
        System.out.println(s);
```

It compiles and runs just perfectly. How? When p is reference of type Person (and which I said Person is not type of Student). Then it must look at object that p is referring to. But how/why does it do that? Shouldn't it just look at reference type because that is what we are passing?

By the way can you send me any link of some reading about this, so I can learn more about it?

Thanks

Comment: Even you assigned it to a Person variable, the object itself has information about what it really is, a Student. The JVM checks at runtime if the cast is acceptable. You can verify this yourself by calling `getClass()` on your object and examining the result.